# I would like to have an observable behaving like a promise

Tags: rxjs, angular5, rxjs5, angular4-httpclient

`var promise = http.get().toPromise();` gives a promise which executes once.

So no matter how much times `promise.then()` is called the http request is done only once.

How can I achieve the same with an observable?: `var observable = http.get().???` so that `obversable.subscribe()` only performs the http request one time?

Comment: Use the `shareReplay` operator.

Comment: ok this did it!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following rxjs operator 'take' like this
import the operators

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and use it like this

```
this.http.get(`${this.url}/${agentId}/intents/${intentId}`)
            .pipe(take(1),
                catchError(error => Observable.throw(error)));
```

but this will only emit a single value once, the latest value, not stop the Observable from calling the request if you call this function again.

Answer (score 1):

The following code did it:
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.http.get("xxx").pipe(shareReplay(1));